# Should we allow quote origin questions?

Tags: discussion

I'll be frank, I am in no way a fan of quote origin questions.  The main issue I have with them is that it's too likely that the quote could originate out of a type of media that isn't on-topic here.  What do we do in that case?  Close it as off-topic?

There are two questions that fall into this category that I'm aware of:  [Origin of knife to a gunfight quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/origin-of-knife-to-a-gunfight-quote), and the new question [Is this quote originally from the dark knight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/is-this-quote-originally-from-the-dark-knight)

Answer (score 10):

My feeling is that even if the quote did originate in a non-film media, *if it is used in a film*, it is still pertinent, as discovering the origin of the quote may yield further insight into the film. For instance, is the Joker referencing a particular character or philosopher?

Insight aside, it also resolves the question of whether a piece of the film's material is original. In my view, inquiring whether a quote is originally from a movie is directly analogous to asking whether the film is an adapted story or original material.

Comment: +1 My vote is also to keep this kind of question

Comment: So, would you say that the requirement should be that it's known that it's used in a film, whether that's the original source or not?

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I myself have mixed feelings about my own quote-question, being a rather trivial *"where's that from"*-question. But then again I still find those things on-topic, as revealing (intentional) inter-references between movies can give good additional insights into the movie apart from a mere identify-problem. But then again, it's probably a question-by-question decision (yes, the unloved standard answer to most meta questions).

And if the original is not from another movie, well, be it so. Other media referenced from a movie can still be relevant for the movie itself (*"On which book is this movie based?"*, "*What is the painting shown in this scene and what does it symbolize?"*).